# How to add two table in a single mvc3 view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

In my mvc3 project i want to add two tables in a single view.I add the two table like this

```
@model IEnumerable<TheRanger.Models.LocalMatch>
@model IEnumerable<TheRanger.Models.Counter>
```

Localmatch and counter are my table name.It shows error.

Here is my coding

```
@using System;
@using System.Data;
@using System.Linq;
@using TheRanger.Models;
@using TheRanger.Class;
@using TheRanger.Controllers;
@{
    TheRanger.Controllers.BaseController bc = new TheRanger.Controllers.BaseController();
    string ClassifiedsFolder = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClassifiedsFolder"];  
}
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@model IEnumerable<TheRanger.Models.LocalMatch>
```

How to i define two tables in a single view.Any idea ?

Comment: _"It shows error."_ - _"it shows some error"_ - _"but i shows error? "_ - _"It shows error"_. - Can you please try not to play a waving hands in air helpless role, but show us **what error** you get?

Comment: I create a class what @MattHouser told.But class name not in the list.So i can't call that class.

Comment: There is no error "class name not in the list" in .NET. If you want help, please just paste the real exception and the line it occurs on in your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a single model class that includes both your lists, then use that model class for your view model.

For example:

```
public class ViewModel
{
  public List<TheRanger.Models.LocalMatch> List1 { get; set; }
  public List<TheRanger.Models.Counter> List2 { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller, you could create an instance of this new model class and populate both list properties.

Then in your view:

```
@model MyApplication.Models.ViewModel

@foreach (var item in Model.List1)
{
}

@foreach (var item in Model.List2)
{
}
```

Comment: The ViewModel pattern is much better approach! +1

Comment: @matt houser i am trying ur method it shows some error in `@model MyApplication.Models.ViewModel` what can i do?

Comment: Your @model line needs to reference your model class directly, don't copy my namespaces.

Comment: It shows error on `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";` this line also.

Comment: Class name viewmodel not in the list of `@model TheRanger.Models`.But i define the class name like viewmodel.

Comment: Make sure your ViewModel class is in the TheRanger.Models namespace, then in your view use `@model TheRanger.Models.ViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

You could place one of the lists in your ViewBag

```
ViewBag.List2 = List2;

@foreach (var item in ViewBag.List2)
{
}
```